# INFO parser, property tree - how can I gather all values according to the single key

Tags: c++, parsing, boost, text

I have `*.txt` file and I want to parse it to the string.

```
key1
{
    key2
    {
        key8 value2 value3
        key9 value3 value3
        key3
        {
            key5 value1
            key6 value2
            key7 value3
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is there are more then one value assigned to the one key.
and when i am trying to get value it just returns me the first one.

```
boost::property_tree::ptree pt;
boost::property_tree::read_info("C:\\NewFolder\\file.txt", pt);
string padShape = pt.get<std::string>("key1.key2.key8");
```

I will be pleased just with having all values in one string object and I will split it by myself.

[Here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/boost_propertytree/parsers.html#boost_propertytree.parsers.info_parser) is website with INFO parser file example where the value is actually separated with white spaces, but I can't find and method that would allow me to read it.

Comment: So what is your actual question?

Comment: How to get multiple values (or one value separated with spaces) assigned to the single key from property tree object?

Answer (score 1):

That's not how the format works. Your example

```
    key8 value2 value3
```

is parsed as

```
    key8 value2
    value3 ""
```

This implies that you can fix it like so:

```
key1
{
    key2
    {
        key8 "value2 value3"
        key9 "value3 value3"
        key3
        {
            key5 "value1"
            key6 "value2"
            key7 "value3"
        }
    }
}
```

See it **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c8e0b153687002a5)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/property_tree/info_parser.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    boost::property_tree::ptree pt;

    read_info(std::cin, pt);
    write_info(std::cout, pt);
}
```

Prints the roundtripped form:

```
key1
{
    key2
    {
        key8 "value2 value3"
        key9 "value3 value3"
        key3
        {
            key5 value1
            key6 value2
            key7 value3
        }
    }
}
```

> The "a website" you link to is the boost documentation site. See the current version here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/property_tree/parsers.html#property_tree.parsers.info_parser. And note how the sample shows exactly how to use double quotes

Comment: Thank you, by writing it to property tree and then again to the text file i can see that the second value is just treated like a next key.
Unfortunately I do not generate this file and i cant change the format to add additional quotes. So do i have then give up this idea and just read this file line by line using getline() ? is it the only way?

Comment: Yes. The could be better ways if there was a known grammar that the input satisfies. I'd probably use Boost Spirit